# Covert input into list elements in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have an input in python that looks like this:

```
20.1
25.9
31.2
33.2
31.2
25.5
28.1
23.2
stop
```

It is a sequence of floating point numbers, each on a separate line. I wish to iterate over them or convert them into list to iterate, but I can't find the right way to do it.
So far I have tried this:

```
    list = [float(n) for n in input().split('\n')]
```

but it only returns me the first value.
I wish to convert all values into a list and keep the integrity of them.

Answer (score 0):

The input function only reads a single line. You need to call it multiple times and check for 'stop'.

```
import sys

mylist = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    if line.startswith('stop'):
        break
    else:
        mylist.append(float(line))

print(mylist)
```

`itertools.dropwhile` can do some of the work for you. Give it a function that returns a False value when the iteration should stop, plus a sequence, and you can do the work in a list comprension.

```
import sys
import itertools

def not_stop_condition(line):
    """Return True unless a line with 'stop' is seen"""
    return not line.startswith('stop')

mylist = [float(line) for line in itertools.takewhile(
    not_stop_condition, sys.stdin)]

print(mylist)
```

Small functions that just implement a simple expression like `not_stop_condition` can be placed in-line in a `lambda`. A `lambda` is just an anonymous function - its called with any number of parameters and returns whatever the expression evaluates to.

```
import sys
import itertools

mylist = [float(line) for line in itertools.takewhile(
    lambda line: not line.startswith('stop'), sys.stdin)]
print(mylist)
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to just use other whitespace (e.g. `' '`) to separate their `input`s?

Comment: @Chris_Rands - we don't know where that input comes from. It may be impossible to change the source. Having line-delimited data piped into a program is normal and its a better way to do things if the input  could get large. Consider a dataset with 10 million floats.

Comment: thanks, it really worked , what is the **lambda** function for?

Comment: I updated to show a progression from a for loop to a list comprehension with lambda.